# Unable to add custom page to Wordpress admin panel

Tags: admin-menu

I am trying to add a page to admin panel and following this tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/nvsK0cTH0So?t=1226)

admin-panel.php

```
function add_menu_to_wpadmin(){
    add_theme_page( 'Admin Contact Us', 'Subscriber list', 'manage_options', 'sublist', 'contactus_admin', 'dashicons-admin-customizer', 110 );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_menu_to_wpadmin');

function contactus_admin(){
    echo "contact us";
}
```

functions.php

```
require get_template_directory().'/admin_panels/sublist_admin.php';
function static_files(){
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'static_files');
```

I tried putting the entire code of `admin-panel.php` inside `functions.php` but it still didn't work. I also tried changing the position parameter from 110 to 6 (all based on numerous tutorials on the internet).

Comment: `add_theme_page` only accepts 5 arguments, not sure what tutorial you saw that had those additional arguments. It's irrelevant anyway, a copy / paste of your first code block adds a `Subscriber list` menu item under `Appearance`, and I see the `contact us` text when I visit that page.

Comment: I reset my wordpress DB and tried the code again, with `add_menu_page` and it worked. Thank you. @Milo